# How to use consumer and supplier instead Reflection in java 8

Tags: java, reflection, consumer

I have a two simple class and use reflection pattern for invoke method.
I want to write module programming.
Suppose we have a table in database that keep modules name:

```
Id  moduleName methodName   ClassName              active
1     sample     a           com.examle.sample        true  
2     SMS        sendSMS     com.example.SMS          false
3     Email      sendEmail   com.example.Email        false 
... ...          ...                       ...
```

When active is true the module must be activated.So when i write a program and compile that, i do not like again compile whole MyApp. So i use reflection pattern to invoke module. please see the codes.

```
public class Sample {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Call Method a");
    }
}
public class SMS {
    public void sendSMS(String str) {
        System.out.println("send SMS ok");
    }
}
public class Email {
    public void sendEmail(String str) {
        System.out.println("send Email ok");
    }
}
public class SampleMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //coonect to database and fetch all record in tables 
       while(record.next){
          if (record.getActive()){        
            Object o = Class.forName(record.getClssName()).newInstance() ;
            Method method = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(record.getMethodName());
            method.invoke(o);
          }                            
       }
    }
```

output

```
   Call Method a
```

So i heard in the java 8, reflection pattern is deprecate and instead that we can use consumer and supplier.

How to use consumer and supplier instead  Reflection in java 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Your example isn't a great use case because it doesn't make sense to use reflection in the first place. Try to provide an example demonstrating the *need* for reflection, rather than *how* it's used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Q42339586 {

    static class Sample {
        void a() { System.out.println("a() called"); }
        void b() { System.out.println("b() called"); }
    }

    static <T> void createInstanceAndCallMethod(
            Supplier<T> instanceSupplier, Consumer<T> methodCaller) {
        T o = instanceSupplier.get();
        methodCaller.accept(o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createInstanceAndCallMethodJava8(Sample::new, Sample::a);
    }

}
```

Here, `createInstanceAndCallMethod` does what is done in your main() Method but it accepts parameters instead.

A `Supplier` is used to create a new instance and a `Consumer` is used to call a particular method on that instance. In the example both method references are passed as both parameters. Instead, you could also use lambda expressions and write `() -> new Sample()` and `o -> o.a()` instead. Please refer to [this official tutorial part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for more information.

The advantages over reflection are obvious:

1. You cannot ask `createInstanceAndCallMethod` to create an instance of a class that doesn't exist.
2. You cannot ask `createInstanceAndCallMethod` to call a method that doesn't exist in a particular class.
3. As a result of both you don't have to deal with any checked Exception.

Of course this does only work when at some place in the code the actual class and method are known, e.g. it's not possible to read class and method name from a properties file and then use Java 8 mechanisms to safely create an instance and call a particular method.

Comment: Not downvoting or anything, but "e.g. it's not possible to read class and method name from a properties file and then use Java 8 mechanisms to safely create an instance and call a particular method." Is it not exactly what  (edited version of) the question aks for ? How can this be the accepted answer ? This does not answer how to dynamically call a given method of a given class, only of pre-known methods and classes.

Comment: Thanks. " it's not possible to read class and method name from a properties file" so how to do for module programming in java 8?

Comment: @GPI It may not address OP's specific use case, but it does explain the context of what he heard about Java 8 and reflection.

Comment: @GPI I'm wondering, too. I have written the answer before the question has been edited which means before it was clear *that* class and method names are stored outside the code. The only valid answer to the edited question is that it's not possible or doesn't bring any benefit by using Supplier and Consumer.

Comment: @Markus Benko if we know the name of class and the name of method in code, seems, it is easier to create an object of class by operator `NEW` and call the known method.

Comment: @Anar Amrastanov I have just answered what initially has been asked for. For the use case presented here it's simply unnecessary but it is all about demonstrating what is possible using Supplier and Consumer and there are use cases where it actually makes sense, i.e. the code that is responsible of supplying a new instance of a particular class does not necessarily know what should be done with that instance next. A DriverManager can create a Connection instance for you but it probably doesn't fire the first SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`Consumer` and `Supplier` are functional interfaces and they do not refer to reflection.

It's different things.

> So i heard in the java 8, reflection pattern is deprecate and instead that we can use consumer and supplier.

Wrong information.

Comment: Functional interfaces and lambdas allow concise dynamic method invocation, which was not possible until Java 8 without using reflection. I think that's what OP is getting at, though the provided example makes it difficult to demonstrate.

Comment: "Functional interfaces allow methods to be referenced concisely" ok, it's possible because of method references and lambda expressions. But what is wrong in my answer? We can create same `Supplier` and `Consumer` interfaces and use them in Java 7. Please explain.

Comment: The key is *concisely*. There's no equivalent for `Class::method` in Java 7 without reflection.

Comment: I agree with you. But I really cannot understand where is the reflection here? In example in the question we need to use reflection because the reference type is `Object`, but object type is `Sample` and the reference doesn't have method `a` of course. In Java 8 we should do the same in this situation.

Comment: I agree that OP's example doesn't help show his point. But it's clearly a contrived example, one that doesn't need reflection to begin with.

Comment: Eventually I did not understand how can you agree with statement, that reflection is deprecated in Java 8. And functional interfaces are used as equivalent to reflection in Java 8.

Comment: Agree with Vusal "function interface" is just kind of syntax sugar, and it can't replace reflection. You could use interfaces and abstract classes since java early days.

Comment: @Vusal can you explain your idea(functional interfaces are used as equivalent to reflection in Java 8) with a example?

Comment: I wrote: "Eventually I did not understand how can you agree with statement, that reflection is deprecated in Java 8. And functional interfaces are used as equivalent to reflection in Java 8." - as you can see from text - I'm not agree with that statement. Maybe the "." sign before "And" confused you.

Comment: @ Vusal. I correct my sentence " i heard in the java 10, reflection pattern is deprecate and instead that we can use consumer and supplier". I mistake in java version.